# I can't fully read and output a xml file

Tags: python, xml, oop

In line 81, I get an error: 'str' object has no attribute 'getCode'
but then I don't understand why lines 80-83 work fine.
I need to implement reading and writing an xml file.
The deliveries class has 2 fields of other classes (parts and providers).
I don't understand how to make a mistake, please give me a hint.

```
import os,xml.dom.minidom
from data import data

class dataxml(data):
    def read(self):
        dom=xml.dom.minidom.parse(self.getInp())
        dom.normalize()
        for node in dom.childNodes[0].childNodes:
            if (node.nodeType==node.ELEMENT_NODE)and(node.nodeName=='providers'):
                code,provider,title,adres,telephone=0,"","","",""
                for t in node.attributes.items():
                    if t[0]=="code":code=int(t[1])
                    if t[0]=="provider":provider=t[1]
                    if t[0]=="title":title=t[1]
                    if t[0]=="adres":adres=t[1]
                    if t[0]=="telephone":telephone=t[1]
                self.getLib().createProviders(code,provider,title,adres,telephone)
            
            if (node.nodeType==node.ELEMENT_NODE)and(node.nodeName=='parts'):
                code,title,articule,price,note=0,"",0,0,""
                for t in node.attributes.items():
                    if t[0]=="code":code=int(t[1])
                    if t[0]=="title":title=t[1]
                    if t[0]=="articule":articule=int(t[1])
                    if t[0]=="price":price=int(t[1])
                    if t[0]=="note":note=t[1]
                self.getLib().createParts(code, title, articule, price, note)
            
            if (node.nodeType==node.ELEMENT_NODE)and(node.nodeName=='deliveries'):
                code,providers,parts,guantity,date=0,None,None,0,""
                for t in node.attributes.items():
                    if t[0]=="code":code=int(t[1])
                    if t[0]=="guantity":guantity=int(t[1])                     
                    if t[0]=="providers":
                        providers=self.getLib().getProviders(int(t[1]))
                    if t[0]=="parts":
                        parts=self.getLib().getParts(int(t[1]))
                    if t[0]=="date":date=t[1]
                self.getLib().createDeliveries(code,providers,parts,guantity,date)
                 
                     

    def write(self):
        dom=xml.dom.minidom.Document()
        root=dom.createElement("shop")
        dom.appendChild(root)
    
        for a in self.getLib().getProvidersList():
            pro=dom.createElement("providers")
            pro.setAttribute('code',str(a.getCode()))
            pro.setAttribute('provider',a.getProvider())
            pro.setAttribute('title',a.getTitle())
            pro.setAttribute('adres',a.getAdres())
            pro.setAttribute('telephone',a.getTelephone())
            root.appendChild(pro)
        
        for p in self.getLib().getPartsList():
            par=dom.createElement("parts")
            par.setAttribute('code',str(p.getCode()))
            par.setAttribute('title',p.getTitle())
            par.setAttribute('articule',str(p.getArticule()))
            par.setAttribute('price',str(p.getPrice()))
            par.setAttribute('note',p.getNote())
            root.appendChild(par)
        
        for b in self.getLib().getDeliveriesList():
            de=dom.createElement("deliveries")
            de.setAttribute('code',str(b.getCode()))
            de.setAttribute('guantity',str(b.getGuantity()))
            de.setAttribute('date',b.getDate())
            
                        
            
            if b.getProviders():
                pc=b.getProviders().getCode()
            else:pc=""
            de.setAttribute('providers',str(pc))

            
            if b.getParts():
                ppc=b.getParts().getCode()          #'str' object has no attribute 'getCode'
            else:ppc=""
            de.setAttribute('parts',str(ppc))
                      
            root.appendChild(de)
            

        
        f = open(self.getOut(),"w")
        #f.write(dom.toprettyxml(encoding='utf-8'))
        f.write(dom.toprettyxml())
```

I tried to do this, but there were only more mistakes.

```
for b in self.getLib().getDeliveriesList():
            de=dom.createElement("deliveries")
            de.setAttribute('code',str(b.getCode()))
            de.setAttribute('guantity',str(b.getGuantity()))
            de.setAttribute('date',b.getDate())
            de.setAttribute('providers',b.getProviders()) #
            de.setAttribute('parts',b.getParts()) #
```

Comment: `I don't understand why lines 80-83 work fine` - what are "lines 80-83"? This site doesn't have line numbers. You need to be more specific. Also, if `getCode()` is not erroring earlier, then it must not be getting run - the `if` statement containing it is probably returning `False`.

Comment: The error is clear: `b.getParts()` returns a string, not a class that has a `getCode()` method.

Comment: @RandomDavis They put the error message in a comment next to the relevant line.

Comment: @Barmar that's where they said they _don't_ get the error though which is why I asked

Comment: @RandomDavis You're right, I misread. But 80-83 should be the line before and the 2 lines after the one with the comment. The reason they work is because there's nothing wrong with `b.getParts()` itself, just with trying to call `getCode()` on the result. And the following lines work when the `if` condition fails.